# Using awk regular expression with gnu find

Tags: find, awk

I am comfortable with AWK regular expressions and would like to use them in GNU `find`. Searching `find`'s manpages I found there are two options called `-regex` and `-regextype` which seemed relevant.

So I tried the following to list all the files with prefix `file` in my directory which looks like this

```
[Desktop/test]$ tree .
.
├── bar
├── file1.pdf
├── file2.pdf
├── file3.pdf
└── foo

0 directories, 5 files
[Desktop/test]$
```

The command

```
[Desktop/test]$ find . -type f -name "*.pdf"
./file3.pdf
./file2.pdf
./file1.pdf
```

works as expected.

But trying

> find . -type f -regextype awk -regex "file"

gave me no output (or errors). Where am I going wrong in the second invocation?

---

**NOTE**

I am using the following version of find on my Linux Mint box

> find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software
>   Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
>   http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html. This is free software: you are
>   free to change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the
>   extent permitted by law.
>
> Written by Eric B. Decker, James Youngman, and Kevin Dalley. Features
>   enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION FTS(FTS_CWDFD)
>   CBO(level=2)

Answer (score 3):

Read the `find` manual:

> -regex pattern
>
> > File  name  matches  regular  expression  pattern.   This  is ***a match on the whole path, not a search***.  For example, to match a file named `./fubar3`, you can use the regular
> >        expression `.*bar.` or `.*b.*3`, but not `f.*r3`.  The regular expressions understood by find are by default Emacs Regular Expressions (except that `.' matches newline),  but
> >       this can be changed with the -regextype option.

So you want

```
find . -type f -regextype awk -regex ".*\.pdf"
```